# getting error for d3-tip in angular2

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am using both d3 and d3-tip along with their @types,

```
 "@types/d3": "^4.4.0",
"@types/d3-tip": "^3.5.2",

"d3": "^4.4.0",
"d3-tip": "^0.7.1",
```

I have below import statement,

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

When trying to compile below typescript code, got below error,

```
 var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function (d) {
            return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'></span>";
        })
```

Error,

```
error TS2339: Property 'tip' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/bugFix/WebPackPOC/src/WebPackApp/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are importing d3 but not d3-tip, which is another package.

```
import 'd3-tip';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in TypeScript.

**EDIT: The latest version of d3-tip at https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip may now be sufficient; I'm about to test.**

====

**WARNING: The information in this section may be out of date.**

I *think* you may need to use this library, which is D3 v4 compatible (also ES5 compatible):

https://github.com/VACLab/d3-tip

If you don't need ES5 compatibility you can just use the ES6 version at:

https://github.com/cgav

====

*(As an aside, being new to D3js and having to upgrade from an older version of D3 to D3 v4, I can tell you that I am not enjoying this process at all, and I am not in any way appreciative of all the incompatibilities and breaking changes. It only gets more frustrating when you have to inject a TypeScript 1.8 -> 2.4 upgrade into the mix.)*